# How splitting the input file is done in the MapReduce framework?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Assume a map-reduce job with m mappers which is fed by an input file F. apparently the mapreduce framework splits F into chunks (64 MB as default value) and feeds each chunk to a mapper. My question is, if I run this mapreduce job a couple of times, is the way chunks are formed the same in all of them? That is, the points from which the mapreduce framework split F remains the same or it may differ?

As an example, assume F contains the following lines:

1,2

3,5

5,6

7,6

5,5

7,7

in the first run the mapreduce forms two chunks  as follows:

Chunk 1:

1,2

3,5

5,6

Chunk 2:

7,6

5,5

7,7

My question is whether the way the split is done remains the same if I run it again?

Besides, does each chunk have a unique name that can be used in the mapper?

Answer (score 1):

**My question is whether the way the split is done remains the same if I run it again?**

It is true that input data gets split into chunks first and then each of these chunk is fed to a mapper. But, it is not always 64M. Perhaps you have got confused with the HDFS block(64M usually) and MR split. Both are totally different things. It is possible though that your split size and block size are same.

Coming to your actual question, yes it is same for all the jobs **which are using the same InputFormat**. Reason being, it is the job of the InputFormat, you are using, to create the splits. To be precise, the logic inside **getSplits(JobContext context)** of your InputFormat governs the split creation. So, if it is same in all the jobs, split creation will also be the same.

**Besides, does each chunk have a unique name that can be used in the mapper?**

Each chunk has 2 things :

- A length in bytes.
- A set of storage locations, which are just hostname strings.

**Edit :**

How to get the name of the file being executed by the mapper :

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

Now, you can open a **FSDataInputStream** on this file and read its content.

Hope it answers your query.

Comment: Thanks.

If my Hadoop program, in each job, each data chunk is related to one file. For example, in the first job, Chunk 1 is related to F1 and Chunk 2 is related to F2, etc. So, the mapper reading Chunk 1 must also read F1. In the next job, a different mapper may read Chunk 1 so it must read F1 as well. If Chunks had a unique name, it would be possible to do this, but as you mentioned they do not have a unique name. Having said that, there is any way to handle this situation?

Comment: Yes. The files will be read. What exactly do you need here?Do you need the filename a particular chunk belongs to?

Comment: Each chunk has a related file that must be read by the mapper. e.g., the chunk 1 is related to F1 and chunk 2 in related to F2. Therefore,  mapper which is fed by chunk 1 must read F1 and mapper fed by chunk 2 must read F2.

Comment: I got that. What is your question?

Comment: If the chunks are not assigned a unique name, how can I do what I want? That is, how to distinguish between different chunks and then read the corresponding related file?

Comment: You don't have to do that. The framework does that for you. You just give the input path and rest is done automatically. But, if you need to get the filename to which the current chunk being processed belongs to for some reason you can do that through **FileSplit**. Please see the edit above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37554/discussion-between-hessam-and-tariq)